# OO PHP - How to create a "generic" database object?

Tags: php, oop, object

Continuing my journey into more advanced OO, I'm trying to come up with the best way of being able to create a class called `database` that can happily use the soon-to-be-deprecated `mysql_` commands, the `mysqli_` library, and perhaps further down the line, other flavours of database as well.

I'd like my calling code to look something like this, for simplicity:

```
$db = new database("MYSQL", $host,$user,$password,$databaseName); 
$db->query("SELECT myField FROM myTable");

while ($ROW = $db->fetch_assoc($QRY)) {
  echo $ROW['myField'] . "<br/>";
}
```

When instantiating the database object, thats the part where i'd hope to specify MYSQL, MYSQLI, MSSQL, or whatever I feel like adding later.

I appreciate I could achieve exactly what I want by implementing `switch` blocks in every method of `database`:

```
class database() {

  function __construct($type,$host,$user,$password,$databaseName) { 

    $this->dbType = $type; 

    switch ($type) {

      case "mysql":
        mysql_dao::connect($host,$user,$password,$databaseName);
        break;

      case "mysqli":
        mysqli_dao::connect($host,$user,$password,$databaseName);
        break;

      case "mssql":
        mssql_dao::connect($host,$user,$password,$databaseName);
        break;

      //other cases
    }

  }

  function query($SQL) {  
    switch ($this->dbType) { 
       case "mysql": mysql_dao::query($SQL); break;
       case "mysqli": mysqli_dao::query($SQL); break; 
       case "mssql": mssql_dao::query($SQL); break;
    }
  }

  function fetch_assoc($SQL) {  
    switch ($this->dbType) { 
       case "mysql": mysql_dao::fetch_assoc($SQL); break;
       case "mysqli": mysqli_dao::fetch_assoc($SQL); break; 
       case "mssql": mssql_dao::fetch_assoc($SQL); break;
    }
  }

  //other methods....

}
```

...But this seems incredibly messy.  Every time a method of `database` was called, the code is checking what type it is and calling the method from a different object.

So my next solution was simply to omit `database` at all, and just use calling code that looks like this:

```
$db = new mysql_dao($host,$user,$password,$databaseName); 
$db->query("SELECT myField FROM myTable");

while ($ROW = $db->fetch_assoc($QRY)) {
  echo $ROW['myField'] . "<br/>";
}
```

...and so we just call the database access object for the type of database we're using, but I don't like that either, if I wanted to shift a whole project from mysql to mysqli, i'd have to seek out all of these object references and change them.  Although this is fairly trivial in a modern PHP editor, it still doesn't feel like it should be the best way (i'm starting to get theoretical instead of practical, now!)

So finally, i'd hoped that I could build the `database` class with a single switch statement:

```
class database {

    function __construct($type,$host,$user,$pass,$db) {    

        switch ($type) {

            default:
            case "MYSQL":
                return new mysql_dao($host,$user,$pass,$db);
                break;

            case "MYSQLI":
                return new mysqli_dao($host,$user,$pass,$db);
                break;

            case "MSSQL":
                return new mssql_dao($host,$user,$pass,$db);
                break;    
        }    

    }

}
```

... and then just implement an interface with all of the other methods being in the classes for the individual database types.  Unfortunately this isn't working either because even though the constructor for `database` returns an instance of another object, I can't call `database->query` because the method doesn't exist in the database object.

As far as I could work out, extending `database` with `mysql_dao` / `mysqli_dao` etc. classes wasn't right either, since you have to call the extended class to use its methods, and I want to call the parent class but use the methods of the child class.  So this suggests that `database` should extend the `dao` classes, but you can't have one child class with multiple potential parents (can you?)

To conclude - I am almost sure I am missing something, and that what I want to do should be both possible and quite straightforward, and I just haven't thought of the right way - can anyone give me a pointer?

Comment: +1 for a good question motivated by “there must be a better way”. I'd be thinking in terms of a factory that returns a proxy object which then delegates to the real object hidden inside, but then again I'm not a PHP programmer.

Comment: Also be aware that different databases tend to support different dialects of SQL; this can make switching between them harder than you'd expect.

Comment: @Donal this is exactly why I was looking at it the way I am, so later methods like say - selectAllRecords($table,$order) - would be able to write SQL the way the particular database needed it to be written.  Although I fear it may not be possible to find a way to remove the need to write ANY SQL outside of the class (when it comes to complex queries), I can definitely get rid of the simple stuff.

Comment: I should perhaps also point out that even though my examples are simplistic, I like to add in a lot of other functionality (such as query profiling) so its not quite just a case of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the fact that what you're doing is reinventing the wheel (take a look at PDO), in general, for cases like this you might want to use something like the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern).

In basic pseudo-code:

```
$db = Database::create('mysql', $host, ...); // gets a MySQLDatabase object
$db = Database::create('mysqli', $host, ...); // gets a MySQLiDatabase object
```

Comment: I think this wins! Its as I had in the last code block of my question, only I had the `return new xxxx` in the constructor, that didn't work.  Moving them into a `create` method works a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use PDO?  It provides a unified way of interfacing with a range of databases (The actual queries it executes have to be written with the target database in mind, but the API is the same regardless of what kind of database you're connecting to).

Comment: I personally hate user-created libs without needs. Rewriting the wheel.

Comment: I'll look into it, but one problem that could occur there is that I don't host everything I write, and so I don't always have access to the PHP config (sometimes I don't even have access to PHP5!)

Comment: PHP 4 isn't supported any more, if you have customers still using it then I'd be inclined to urge them to upgrade.  For their own protection if nothing else, PHP 4 contains vulnerabilities that will never be fixed and using it basically leaves the server it's running wide open to attack.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation, I would generally :

- Define some `DAOInterface`, with methods such as `connect`, `query`, `fecthAll`, ...

  - all class that connect to the database will have to implement that interface
  - which means that your `mysql_dao`, `mysqli_dao`, ... will implement that interface

Then, when working with those classes, the main advantage is :

- You'll later instanciate, as a `$db` variable, either `mysql_dao` or `mysqli_dao`, but always get an object that implements `DAOInterface`
- Which means you will be sure that you can invoke all those methods, on your `$db` object

After that, there will only be one place where you have to choose between `mysql_dao` and `mysqli_dao` : it's when you are instanciating one of those two, assigning the result to `$db`.

Then, as your know for sure that `$db` is an object that implements `DAOInterface`, you know for sure that you will always be able to call the same methods on that object.

Comment: That's one of the solutions I came up with (I just didn't talk about the interface in the original question) but that still means I have to call the DAO directly, and so if I wanted to change, there'd be changes to the calling code in every page that used the database (not accounting for using includes etc).

Comment: There would not be any change anywhere *(except where you instanciate the DAO and assign it to $db)*, as long as all your DAO implement the same interface : the code that uses the methods of that interfaces will remain exactly the same.

Comment: I understand that - I was just trying to be even lazier :-) With instancing code always being `new database` regardless of which actual DAO it used.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the functionality to be functional you will need to pass and return parameter as references as in the following example :

```
 public function &Query($sql){
     $var = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
     return $var;
 }

 public function Fetch(&$cur){
     return mysql_fetch_array($cur);
 }
```

The "&" represent the reference of the variable not just a copy for more documentation :http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

What you are trying to do works well. I created on to interface a MySQL database, but I'm sure you'll find a way to create an object for the different type of DB.